# react native react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation:processReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Everything was working fine then suddenly I'm getting following error

```
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex

:react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.413 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing one line in node_modules/react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation/android/lib/build.gradle
from

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
```

Comment: If you want to use the newest support library, you will need to use android-P SDK (since the newest support library uses resources that were added in P). You can download the android-P preview in the SDK manager and then update your compile SDK version in your build.gradle file.